# Sending an unchecked value to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my code:

```
  $('#form').on('change', 'input', function (e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var cb = $(this);

      if(cb.is(':checked')){
        send_data(this);
      }
      else{
        this.value=0;
        send_data(this);
      }

      //if(!(this.checked)){
        //$(this).val(0);
      //}

    });
```

send_data function:

```
  function send_data(obj) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'some.php',
    async:  true,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success:  function (msg) {
      console.log(msg);

    }
  });
}
```

some function:

```
      var inp_f =document.createElement('input');
  inp_f.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  inp_f.setAttribute('name', intrst);
  inp_f.setAttribute('value', 0);

  var inp = document.createElement('input');
  inp.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  inp.setAttribute('id', intrst);
  inp.setAttribute('name', intrst);
  inp.setAttribute('value', 1);
```

I have looked over several questions, so before you flag me for duplicate post; none of them have solved my issue. I have created a function that dynamically creates inputs. When that input is checked a value of 1 is sent. When it is unchecked I am trying to then send a value of 0 through ajax call. I have created the invisible field for some reason it does recognize it. So I then attempted to changed the value of `this.value=0` that does not set until after the script has ran. Then as long as the page is not reloaded the value remains 0.

EDIT: Reordered the input elements and the console is still showing `$(this).val() = 0`

Comment: really, I don't think there is need to use javascript and there are plenty right answers

you must add for each checkbox input hidden input - but - in right order:

    `<input type='hidden' value='0' name='myCheckBox'>`
    `<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='myCheckBox'>`

Comment: @jDolba I reordered the elements and when i checked the console the value once it is unchecked is still 0

Comment: another problem can be that, you pass to method `send_data(this);` ... but in this metod you handle with this parameter as it is jquery object, but it is not .... try pass `send_data($(this));`


there are more possible problems, how exactly you creating in document new input elements ?  are they in right <form> at the moment when you call send_data ?